# How to use a shared network folder like a local one in Gnome to download and save files?

Tags: linux, gnome, shared-folders, nautilus

I would like to be able to download a file from my web browser to a shared network folder.

I am actually able to read and write to shared network folders when opening the file browser (Nautilus), but I cannot open a file or folder from a local program such Codium, Chromium…

See screenshots below.

Access the files in the file browser:

> [image: access the files]

No access the files in Chromium:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two programs you mention (Chromium and all Chromium-based programs) specifically disable the remote file access support in the file chooser, as it's done through GTK/GLib and those programs aren't actually GTK-based – they only call its file chooser dialog.

You'll need to go through `/run/user/1000/gvfs` to access the remote locations currently connected in GNOME, or use `sshfs` or `mount -t smb3` to create system-wide mounts.

Comment: thanks, do you mean browsing the path to /run/user/1000/gvfs from chromium file chooser ? this appears empty... I am gonna check the other solution you provided.

Comment: You need to open the share in a file browser first so that it gets mounted, then you will have an entry like ```smb-share:server=nas542.local,share=daten``` in ```/run/user/1000/gvfs```. But I just noticed that mounted (!) network shares are directly accessible via "Other Locations".